# ordenar lista de enteros por frecuencia situando los datos iguales seguidos

Tags: python, array, lista, ordenamiento

me piden ordenar una lista de enteros como se muestra a continuación:

input: [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4] output: [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]

El código que tengo es el siguiente::

```
def frequency_sort(items):
    result = sorted(items, key = items.count, reverse = True)
    return result
```

El problema es que el output que saca es: [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 6]

No sé muy bien como implementar que, a parte de ordenarlos por frecuencia, ponga los números iguales seguidos.

Nota: los números que se repitan con la misma frecuencia deberán ser ordenados por orden de aparición en la lista

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sin usar ninguna librería:

```
def frequency_sort(lista):
    salida = []
    for valor in lista:
        for i in range(len(salida)):
            if valor == salida[i][0]:
                salida[i] = (valor, salida[i][1] + 1)
                break
        else:
            salida.append((valor, 1))

    resultado = []
    for valor, cuenta in salida:
        resultado.extend([valor] * cuenta)
    return resultado
```

La lista `salida` contiene pares `(valor, cuenta)`, con el valor encontrado y las veces que aparece.

Esta lista se construyendo recorriendo la primera lista. Por cada elemento, se recorre `salida` buscando un par correspondiente a ese valor.

Si se encuentra el valor, se calcula una nueva tupla y se reemplaza la existente en la lista.

Si no se encuentra el valor, se genera una nueva tupla `(valor, 1)` y se agrega a la salida.

Esto asegura que en la lista `salida` los items aparezcan en el mismo orden de la entrada.

El paso final es recorrer `salida` transformando cada tupla `(valor, cuenta)` en la correspondiente repetición de valores `valor, valor, .., valor` para extender la lista `resultado`.

#### Demo

```
def frequency_sort(lista):
    salida = []
    for valor in lista:
        for i in range(len(salida)):
            if valor == salida[i][0]:
                salida[i] = (valor, salida[i][1] + 1)
                break
        else:
            salida.append((valor, 1))

    resultado = []
    for valor, cuenta in salida:
        resultado.extend([valor] * cuenta)
    return resultado


lista = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4] # ff
print(frequency_sort(lista))
```

produce:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edición**

El algoritmo genera la lista final expandida.

Comment: CandidMoe, lo que el OP busca según entendí es [4,4,4,4,6,6,2,2] es decir, que ordene por frecuencia pero que el resultado quede con todos los números iguales juntos, es decir, la cadena de salida es del mismo tamaño que la de entrada pero con los valores ordenados. Pero si la cadena de entrada fuera  [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6, 2, 6] la salida esperada sería  [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 6] porque en este caso el 2 apareció primero en la entrada

Comment: @HeytalePazguato. Gracias. Arreglado.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por responder. no sabeis lo mucho que ayudais a los pobres programadores novatos como yo :)

Answer (score 0):

Compañero, te adjunto una propuesta de solución:

```
import itertools

eval = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4] 


def frequency_sort(items):
    
    #pseudo ordenado
    change_order = sorted(items, key = items.count, reverse = True)
    
    #valores únicos ordenados
    order_prev = sorted(set(change_order), key=change_order.index) 
    
    #frecuencia de valores ordenados
    frec_prev = [eval.count(val) for val in order_prev]
    
    #combinación final
    last_order = list()
    for i in range(len(order_prev)):
        last_order = last_order + list(itertools.repeat(order_prev[i], frec_prev[i]))
    
    return last_order
    
print(frequency_sort(eval))
```

Saludos y éxitos.